# Zend Framework 2 - Doctrine 2 Model Forms

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-form, zend-framework2, modelform

Is there a way to autocreate forms based on the models I defined within Doctrine?

In `Django` its a basic feature. I found some old sources where someone had tried to implement it by himself... but nothing up-to-date or official-looking

These model forms save loads of time. I do ask myself why people don't complain about this (possibly) missing feature...

Comment: I think Zend/Form is able to build from annotations. You may check that out. Haven't tried it yet, through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zend 2 cannot create a form from the Entity itself. Doctrine 2 is not even part of the framework or tied to it as close as to Symfony 2.

You may use annotations in your entity to hint all necessary information for creating a form from it using the annotation builder.

For a deeper understanding how this works I would suggest you to look it up in the [Zend 2 Documentation](https://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html#using-annotations).

Comment: I wonder: Is there a connection between the shown annotation form and the data model?

Comment: Not really you could use the annotations on any class.

Comment: its not working for me. i opened a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13974969/1331671

Comment: I've answered your new question. Hope it helps ;)