# Zend Framework 2 - Annotation Forms don't work

Tags: php, forms, model, zend-form, zend-framework2

Thanks to [@Hikaru-Shindo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13968158/1331671) I looked into `AnnotationForms` which seem to be the best available as a work-around for `ModelForms`. But the example shown [here](https://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html#using-annotations) doesn't work for me.

```
use Zend\Form\Annotation\AnnotationBuilder;

$builder = new AnnotationBuilder();
$form    = $builder->createForm('User');
```

Looking at this code I wonder where the `AnnotationBuilder` knows where to look for this user form. Especially because in the annotation in the form def there is a lowercase 'user'

```
@Annotation\Name("user")
```

I put the form def code into 'MyModule/Form/UserForm.php' and the lower code into my Controller. Is this the right way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This could be your entity (and form definition) for a user entity (shortend version):

```
namespace Application\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Zend\Form\Annotation as Form;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="application_user")
 * @Form\Name("user")
 * @Form\Hydrator("Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ObjectProperty")
 */
class User
{

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @Form\Exclude()
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     * @Form\Filter({"name":"StringTrim"})
     * @Form\Validator({"name":"StringLength", "options":{"min":1, "max":25}})
     * @Form\Validator({"name":"Regex", "options":{"pattern":"/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]{0,24}$/"}})
     * @Form\Attributes({"type":"text"})
     * @Form\Options({"label":"Username:"})
     */
    protected $username;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=90, unique=true)
     * @Form\Type("Zend\Form\Element\Email")
     * @Form\Options({"label":"Your email address:"})
     */
    protected $email;

}
```

And to use this form:

```
use Zend\Form\Annotation\AnnotationBuilder;

$builder = new AnnotationBuilder();
$form    = $builder->createForm('Application\Entity\User');
// Also possible:
// $form = $builder->createForm(new Application\Entity\User());
```

So the builder needs the fully qualified name of your definition class.
The name you set using the annotations is the name of the form used for example to create the form's id attribute.

If you have a use statement for it you could also abond the namespace:

```
use Zend\Form\Annotation\AnnotationBuilder;
use Application\Entity\User;

$builder = new AnnotationBuilder();
$form    = $builder->createForm('User');
// Also possible:
// $form = $builder->createForm(new User());
```

Comment: great answer, one question remaining: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975744/zend-framework-2-doctrine-2-use-of-documentor-tags

Comment: Just a little thing: Code convention has it that there may be one USE Statement per line, ending with a semicolon. Both work, just as general information about coding standards ;)

Comment: Depends on the coding standard you are using @Sam. I do like this version better ;) But edited it in regards to the ZF standards.

Comment: How do you go about adding the CSRF and Submit buttons? there doesn't seem to be an example anywhere that includes how to do that. Every tutorial stops before them. I've read about creating a Fieldset but do I really need to create another class to hold what is essentially already my fieldset (the entity)?

Comment: On first tought I think you need to add those fields manually on form creation. But I'm not really sure about that since I don't really use annotation forms - I just haven't tried it yet. You may submit a question here on SO regarding this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem. The solution is a mindbreaker. Took me long time to find out. 
The problem lies in the first line of your annotation code.

```
/**
```

This line is normally used for commenting your annotation code, but allmost everybody leaves it empty. Normally no issues, but this is somehow causing problems in the form annotations. You should either add some comment, add a space, or move your first line of code up. So:

```
/** Some comment to make this annotation work
/** (<-- a space)
```

or start like this:

```
/** @ORM\Column(type="string")
```

Don't ask me why this is happening, found the solution somewhere online. As I understood the bug has been reported.

Comment: WTF? This solved it for me too! Exactly the same files work on the server and used to work on my local but suddenly stopped.

Comment: Same issues here was well. They should definitely solve this problem. I am using the latest version of Zend Framework 2 (2.2.5) and the bug still exists!