# Zend Framework 2 - Doctrine 2 - Use of Documentor Tags

Tags: php, tags, doctrine-orm, entity, zend-framework2

I'm new to `Doctrine` and `Zend`. I realized that in nearly all entity models (whereever I read a tutorial) I saw these documentor tags like  `@var` or `@property`.

They aren't required, right? So is it a bad thing to leave them out? It's really time-consuming adding and altering them for every attribute in my Entities.

Comment: Some IDE's will add documentor annotations for you, and pre-fill what they can. I know Netbeans does this for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is simply a good habbit of programming and documenting your code. It helps your IDE to function better and makes it easier for other people (including yourself in a year from now on) to maintain your code.