# ZF2 Doctrine Form Annotation Type Select

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, zend-form2

i have a problem with the annotation for a select Element. I Always get an input field.

```
<div class="form-group "><label>test:</label><input type="number" name="test" class="form-control" value="1"></div>
```

Here is my Annotation.

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="test", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @Annotation\Type("Zend\Form\Element\Select")
 * @Annotation\Filter({"name":"StringTrim"})
 * @Annotation\Options({"label":"test:", "value_options":{"0":"yes","1":"no"}})
 */
private $persistent = '0';
```

did i forget something ?

kind regards :)

UPDATE 2014-04-23

in my action i create the form with

```
    $builder = new DoctrineAnnotationBuilder($entityManager);
    $form = $builder->createForm( $user );
    $form->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($entityManager,'Test\Entity\Test'));
```

and this is my view

```
    <?
    $form = $this->form;
    $form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('user/edit', array('id' => $this->id))); //'contact/process'));
    $form->setAttribute('method', 'post');

    echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
    echo $this->formCollection($form);
    echo $this->form()->closeTag();
```

Comment: How do you render the form in view file?

Comment: Well, I have the very same problem. Created an ORM/Column of type integer and assigned an @Annotation\Type Zend\Form\Element\Select but I'm getting exception "Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormSelect::render requires that the element is of type Zend\Form\Element\Select" because I'm trying to render the element with formSelect view helper and Doctrine created an element of type Zend\Form\Element\Number. An alternative would be to declare a new Doctrine ORM entity for the possible values of "test", that already worked for me for another kind of member vars like "language" and "security question"

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this? I have exactly the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

[Check the answer here...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15817761/1697459)

That might help, might also not help, but at least worth a try...

Comment: actually the annotation itself is working. i try it, but it makes no difference. thx :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old, but for reference, this is the entity property docblock within a Doctrine 2 Annotated entity that works for me to render a fixed list select:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="layout", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
 * @Annotation\Type("Zend\Form\Element\Select")
 * @Annotation\Options({
 *   "label":"Layout:",
 *   "value_options":{"":"", "one-page":"One Page", "multi-page":"Multi-page"}
 * })    
 */
private $layout;
```

Using latest ZF 2.3.*.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Want just through Annotation get my Select box built. 
I think that Hydrator does not do it really  (Doctrine 2 ORM v 1,*   and ZF2.5).

Just use Iterator and use

Entity:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Zend\Form\Annotation;
    /**
     * @var \Backend\Entity\Mastercategory
     *
     * @Annotation\Type("Zend\Form\Element\Select")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Backend\Entity\Mastercategory")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="sub_pid", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $subPid;
```

Controller:

```
//mastercategories  is my Object EntityClass actually with getter_setter
$arr = new \ArrayIterator($mastercategories);
        $masterToArr = array();
        while ($arr->valid())
        {
            $mid = $arr->current()->getId();
            $mname = $arr->current()->getMasterName();
            $masterToArr[$mid] = $mname;
            $arr->next();
        }
        $form->get('subPid')->setOptions(array('type' => 'select', 'value_options' => $masterToArr));
```

Viewer:

```
<?php echo $this->formSelect($form->get('subPid')); ?>
```

I know this is not a good Idea to fill out Controller with stuff like this but it works fine.